# Data storage and retrieval in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am building a chrome extension where I need to use data storage. The operation of the extension is as below:

- The extension captures the url of any get or post request
- If the URL is already present in the storage key:value pair as key then I retrieve the value and show it somehow in the browser
- If the URL is not present in the storage then I call an API that does some operation on the URL and returns a response. Then I store the URL-response pair as key:value in the storage. The reason I am doing this, so that I don't have to call the API next time the same URL appears. I will just check my storage then.

I have written the following code for setting the values in storage.

```
chrome.storage.sync.set({user_url: show_action}, function() {
    console.log('Key is ' + user_url);
    console.log('Value is set to ' + show_action);
});
```

The `user_url` variable has the captured URL from a request. `show_action` variable holds the response from the API call. 
I am trying to retrieve the value using the following code:

```
chrome.storage.sync.get([user_url], function(result) {
    console.log(result);
    console.log('Value currently is ' + result.user_url);
    if(result.user_url == null || result.user_url == undefined)
        call_api = true;
    else
        show_action = result.user_url;
});
```

This is not working as expected. I am getting a blank `result` with no key-value pairs with `user_url` as key. Although it must be there because I am setting the value before retrieval. Then I tried to put `user_url` as a string literal in the get call like this:

```
chrome.storage.sync.get(["user_url"], function(result) {
    console.log(result);
    console.log('Value currently is ' + result.user_url);
});
```

When this is done the result is something like this in console log:

```
{user_url: true}
user_url: true
Value currently is true
```

So, the `user_url` itself is being set as key instead of the value in it. 
My question is how do I set the URL as key and when I call by the URL I get the desired output? And also how to handle the situation when I call by the URL but that is not present in the storage?

Comment: Looks like a you're [modifying a variable inside an asynchronous callback](/q/23667086/) (should be used inside the callback) and incorrectly accessing a [variable object key](/q/2274242/) (should be result[user_url]).

Comment: Then how should I do it to get the result?

Comment: I've already indicated that in my comment and the topics I've linked should contain more examples.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like that on this line `chrome.storage.sync.set({user_url: show_action}` `user_url` is not translated automatically, and is considered as a key of the object you pass to `chrome.storage.sync.set`.

You might want to do it as follows:

```
let data = {};
data[user_url] = show_action;

chrome.storage.sync.set(data, function() {
    console.log('Key is ' + user_url);
    console.log('Value is set to ' + show_action);
});
```